# tensorflow loading meta graph hardcoded reshape dimensions

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning

I have a fairly complex architecture that I'm still experimenting with, and a big part of this experimentation involves tweaking the architecture, retraining and seeing how it performs. In order to avoid explicitly modifying the architecture at test time, reverting it to the exact state it was when the checkpoint was saved, I'm loading the graph from the `.meta` file in the checkpoint directory.

I am having issues with the `batch_size`, which tends to be saved in the graph and gives me troubles at inference time when I test 1 sample at a time, i.e. `batch_size=1`. The first issue was with the placeholder I was using to feed the data, which I solved by setting `batch_size=None` (the first dimension) when declaring it.

Now, I have a part of my network that is roughly based on this [spatial transformer](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/transformer) which involves quite a bit of reshaping. Everything works fine at training time, but if I try to load the `.meta` changing the batch size, I encounter errors like:

```
InvalidArgumentError (see above for traceback): Input to reshape is a tensor with 98304 values, but the requested shape has 1572864
[[Node: Reshape = Reshape[T=DT_FLOAT, Tshape=DT_INT32, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/gpu:0"](g_transformer/_transform/concat, pack_5)]]
[[Node: g_transformer_1/_transform/Reshape_6/_333 = _Recv[client_terminated=false, recv_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0", send_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/gpu:0", send_device_incarnation=1, tensor_name="edge_520_g_transformer_1/_transform/Reshape_6", tensor_type=DT_FLOAT, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"]()]]
```

Where `98304` is  `1572864/16`, with 16 being the training batch size. Some posts fixed similar issues by setting the first dimension of the reshape to `-1`, which is something that I cannot do here due to other `-1` in other dimensions.

So, the question is: I use this to load the trained model

```
self.loader = tf.train.import_meta_graph(meta)
self.loader.restore(self.sess, os.path.join(fn, ckpt_name))
```

but how can I prevent the metagraph from hardcoding the reshape dimensions, effectively preventing me from changing the batch size at test time?

**EDIT:** some further experiments. If I load the graph and fetch the node that it's causing the issue with

```
 a = g.get_tensor_by_name('g_transformer_1/_transform/Reshape_6:0')
```

it says:

```
<tf.Tensor 'g_transformer_1/_transform/Reshape_6:0' shape=(?, 128, 384, ?) dtype=float32>
```

and the `?` are exactly where I'd want them to be, the first one in particular, since it's the one controlling the batch size.
But if I run an eval on that variable and feed something where the first dimension is not exactly the same used in training, it ends up with the aforementioned shape error.

Comment: I am running in to a similar problem right now. Did you ever resolve this? What was the solution if so?